# Why Hive not support underscore?

Tags: hive, hiveql

why this sql can execute success：

```
select
a.detail as detail ,
b.detail as parent_detail
from
    db.info as a
   join db.info as b on a.parent_id=b.id;
```

but follow sql is execute fail:

```
select
info.detail as detail ,
parent_info.detail as parent_detail 
from
    db.info as info
   join db.info as parent_info on info.parent_id=parent_info.id;
```

so, why hive not support underscore in an alias? (hive version is 1.1.0)

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: Can you share you error log ?

Comment: sorry, above sql not the original error sql. I already find the error, I alias table name to `level`,but the table have a column is 'level',so when sql execution, the error is  : 
 FAILED: SemanticException Column level Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries